# How do I count total lines and create new/Select sheet in one csv file using progress 4GL?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I am new to progress 4GL. I have a CSV file that has data for the first 2 rows. 1st-row data is for the list of users and 2nd-row data is for users to be deactivated.

In my program, if I selected flag yes then the program should check the second row in CSV file and store it to a temp table. Please take a look at what I have tried from my side as it is not helping me to focus only on the second row in CSV instead it is taking all the data including 1st-row data as well.

I really appreciate if you tell me how can I create new/move to a sheet(sec) in CSV file and parse the data using progress 4GL

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE  tt_sec7Role
   FIELD  ttsec_role AS CHARACTER.

DEFINE VARIABLE  v_dataline AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE v_count  AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.

EMPTY TEMP-TABLE  tt_sec7Role.

input from "C:\Users\ast\Desktop\New folder\cit.csv".
  repeat:
     import unformatted v_dataline. 
     if v_dataline <> '' then
     do:
        do v_count = 1 to NUM-ENTRIES(v_dataline,','): 
           create tt_sec7Role.
           ttsec_role = entry(v_count,v_dataline,',').
        end.
     end. /* if v_dataline <> '' then */
  end. /*repeat*/
  input close.
  v_count = 0.
  FOR EACH  tt_sec7Role:
      v_count = v_count + 1.
  END.
  MESSAGE v_count.
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply need to count rows just add an integer and increase it after each import statement:

```
define variable counter as integer no-undo. 
input from "C:\Users\ast\Desktop\New folder\cit.csv".
repeat:
    import unformatted v_dataline. 
    counter = counter + 1.
    if v_dataline <> '' then
    do:
        //If you only want to do this on line 2
        if counter = 2 then do v_count = 1 to NUM-ENTRIES(v_dataline,','): 
           create tt_sec7Role.
           ttsec_role = entry(v_count,v_dataline,',').
        end.
    end. /* if v_dataline <> '' then */
end. /*repeat*/
input close.
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you determine if you should read that second row, create a record in your temp-table, then do another import. Then copy that part of the data to your tt, and at the end just cycle through your tt and export the fields with a comma as a delimiter.

Comment: the question is how can I determine the 2nd row in CSV?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by determine? If you mean read it, it's just doing another import statement